# Swift 3: sort array of filenames independent from extension

Tags: arrays, string, sorting, swift3

Consider this array:

```
let files = ["file2.tif", "file33.jpg", "file11.jpg"]
```

I would like to sort this array so the result would be

```
sortedFiles = ["file2.tif", "file11.jpg", "file33.jpg"]
```

There are two problems here that I don't know how to approach:

1) how to ignore the file extension when sorting

2) how to make sure that "file2" is put in front of "file11"

Thank you so much for your insights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to cast the strings to `NSString` and use Foundation methods `deletingPathExtension` and `compare:options:.numeric`

```
let files = ["file2.tif", "file33.jpg", "file11.jpg"]

let sortedFiles = files.sorted(by: {
   return ($0 as NSString).deletingPathExtension.compare(($1 as NSString).deletingPathExtension, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending
})
```

Comment: Cool. I'll give it a try